# how to delete a datomic schema and what happens to the associated data?

Tags: clojure, datomic

I'm curious as to how easy it is to change your schema and data given Datomic's transaction based system. Can someone shed some light?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to retract your schema.

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/datomic/7-9lUE9Nm4k

Comment: Just found this out the "hard way" -- Every attribute in the schema gets a magic number, so putting new attributes in can mess up the order.  Which is fine if you're just testing, but in production, only add attributes (and perhaps never switch their order around)